# How to add clickable icons in Word press website using a builder

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

Hii I've a project I want to add some icons at the top of my website that will show various services provided by my site.
I want something like this example image

[image]

Here's what I've done

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On elementor you can add a link to your icon or your image in the settings.

With the icons module you can also configure the hover too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the svg code of icons, i recommend using text title widget. It works as an html and of course you can add your desired styles. It is of course the best solution if you want to have full customization.